# finding the index of a stack with java (only using methods push, pop, and peek)

Tags: java

New programmer learning java here! I'm trying to count how many steps does it take for a loop to stop taking what the user inputted into account. Bear in mind, there is limitation set by some guy in school *sigh* you can only use some methods in stack. These methods are push, pop, and peek.

Input:

- first *input* is how many elements added.
- second *input* is a list of books you want added.
- third *input* is when do you want the loop to stop.

I want to store the key index when it stops for example the inputs are:

```
4
Operating System
Algorithm and Data Structures
Web Programming
Computer Network
Web Programming
```

If the last input is Web Programming then according to the idea of Stack, the expected index should be 1 because when using a stack you always peek() or see the last element you input. The same thing happens with pop() where you remove the last element of the stack.

So here's what I got:

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //methods should only use push, pop, peek

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Stack<String> books = new Stack<>();

        //n first
        int n = in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine();

        //n second
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            books.push(in.nextLine());
        }

        //n third
        String str = in.nextLine();
        int index = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            //insert solution here
        }
        System.out.println(index);
    }
}
```

Here is my current solution for it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (books.peek().contains(str)){
                break;
            }
            books.pop();
            index++;
        }
```

I've been working on a solution so far and brute forcing but instead of returning the value of the index when it breaks, it returns the value of n or the size of the stack.

another example using my solution, when these are the inputs:

```
4
Operating System
Algorithm and Data Structures
Web Programming
Computer Network
Computer Network
```

the output is supposed to be:

```
0
```

but instead I get:

```
4
```

Which probably means the condition of "books.peek().contains(str)" doesn't actually break the loop properly.

Really appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: Also really confused on what to put in title since english is not my first language and im kinda lacking knowledge in programming terms

Comment: The index is one less than the size because it starts from zero.

Comment: I dont think thats it since using my solution, the output is 5 unless the input is "Web Programming" which is really odd

Comment: Description is little bit confusing :/ Can you please describe little bit more about why output is 1 for your given input? Which value's index you want to show in output? Also it would be helpful to understand if you show another example.

Comment: @Md.FaisalHabib I added another examples, and changed the title, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Find out the position of a string in the stack which will be given in query (considering first position will be 0):

Sample code:

```
String str = in.nextLine();
int index = 0;
while(!books.empty())   // traverse whole stack until it gets empty
{
    String currString = books.peek();
    books.pop();    
    if(str == currString) break;
    else index++;
}

System.out.println(index);
```

You can also check the use of `indexOf` in stack.

Resources:

- [Stack indexOf() method in Java with Example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stack-indexof-method-in-java-with-example/)
- [Stack Class in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stack-class-in-java/)
- [Java Stack](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-stack)